# Can I add a reference letter when I apply job?

Tags: software-industry, resume, new-job, applications, references

I am currently studying at University and I done a summer internship and I got a great reference letter.

I want to apply a graduate job and it is so related my past internship. 
So I have a question that Can I add my reference letter when apply job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I add my reference letter when apply job?

This will greatly depend on the way this specific company handles their applications (online, hand in some papers, etc.).

I would say you **include it *only* if their application steps and documents allow/ask for such, either explicitly** (*"please include any relevant reference letter for your position"*) **or by less explicit means** (*"any other information relevant to your application?"*).

Sometimes including it "just because" may be seen as you trying to apparent a better profile than it really is, which could affect your chances of landing the job. Sometimes you will not be even able to include them, as their online forms may not have space for it contemplated.

Yet another alternative if you can't graciously include the letter, is to **mention such in your CV** where you list that past job. This way it will not be too "aggressive" but still cause an impact, and be able to provide it if asked further on the recruitment process.

Comment: Thank you for answer, I just want to make clear. This job is recommended from someone and I talked the company owner with phone (because I could not find any specific application place) and he said "Please send your document CV, cover letter etc" now I am wondering is it good idea to send all of it?

Comment: @Axis cover letter is different from Reference letters. However, it seems that they indeed said **"etc."**, so it could be safe to assume they are giving you chance to support your application the way you want to. If that is so, then I see no problem with sending the letter also.